# How to calculate the interaction between the condition and the genotype

Tags: anova, two-way

I am struggling with this one problem. I am investigating the effect of the treatment on the growth of the plants. I did the t-test analysis to check the effect of the treatment in every genotype I have, but now I was requested to check the interaction between genotype and the treatment, so if the response to the treatment of the mutant differs from the response of the wild type. Do you have any advices on how to do that? I was trying to answer it with two-way anova followed by post test to compare different pairs of groups, but I am not sure it really answers the question i am asking.

Answer (score 0):

I think if the requirements for an anova are given (normal distribution of residuals and homogeneity of variances of the different groups), then your suggestion is very reasonable.